# Converting string into number, result in a different number

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to convert a bigint passed from php, into a integer in nodejs, the result is always different, I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
> var a = parseInt('135601920000000040', 10);
undefined
> a
135601920000000030
> var a = parseFloat('135601920000000040');
undefined
> a
135601920000000030
> var n = Number('135601920000000040');
undefined
> n
135601920000000030
```

Not only node.js, it also happen to js interpreter in Firefox

Comment: have you tried different numbers or only 135601920000000040? if you tried different, what are the results? can you see any pattern that may lead to a solution?

Comment: Fx too: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VqQDH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Number type in javascript is represented as double precision floating point, so, it a value passed to parseInt, parseFloat etc is more than 9007199254740992 ([ECMAScirpt Numbers specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)) it is rouned to fit the Number type.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. javascript don't have a 64bit integer, same as php